# Fastai / Pytorch - how to get Precision-Recall matrix for multiclass classification

Tags: pytorch, classification, precision-recall, fast-ai

I have a baseline image classifier which is highly inaccurate due to a huge class imbalance. Now I need to merge some small classes into bigger ones. In order to choose which classes to merge together, I need to get Precision-Recall metrics for each class. Just like sklearn’s `ClassificationReport`

How can I do it in fastai or pytorch? Most preferably, I want to achieve this result in fastai, but torch is okay.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```py
interpretation = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learner)
```

And then you will have 3 useful functions:

- `confusion_matrix()` (produces an `ndarray`)
- `plot_confusion_matrix()`
- `most_confused()` <-- Probably the best match for your scenario